# How to set up anonymous read-only samba shares

Tags: linux, debian, network-shares, android, samba

I'm confused with the way to setup samba shares on a LAN for different clients.

Here's my smbd.conf file :

```
[global]
    workgroup = TOMMY
    server string = NAS server
    dns proxy = no
    interfaces = lo eth0 
    bind interfaces only = true
    log level = 2
    max log size = 10000
    syslog = 0
    panic action = /usr/share/samba/panic-action %d
    security = user
    encrypt passwords = true
    passdb backend = tdbsam
    obey pam restrictions = yes
    map to guest = Bad User

    server signing = mandatory
    ntlm auth = no

    load printers = no
    printing = bsd
    printcap name = /dev/null
    disable spoolss = yes

    unix charset = UTF-8

[tmp]
    comment = Shared data folder
    path = /home/data
    read only = no
    create mask = 0666
    force create mode = 0666
    directory mask = 0777
    force directory mode = 0777
    guest ok = yes

[photos]
    comment = Photos
    path = /home/photos

[music]
    comment = Music files
    path = /home/music
    guest ok = yes

[documents]
    comment = Documents repository
    path = /home/docs
    guest ok = yes
```

What I'm trying to do is to have *tmp* share writable by anyone without authentication, *music* and *documents* shares should be accessible by anyone too, but read-only, and *photos* should only be accessible read only by authentified users.

I don't share any printers. Everything works fine with desktop Linux clients (Ubuntu and Archlinux), and with Windows 7 clients, but I can't get my Android Lollipop tablet to connect to the shares.

Samba logs show the following error when I'm trying to connect from the tablet :

```
[2016/04/24 00:19:46.919962,  2] ../source3/auth/auth.c:315(auth_check_ntlm_password)
    check_ntlm_password:  Authentication for user [GUEST] -> [GUEST] FAILED with error NT_STATUS_NO_SUCH_USER
```

I'm using ES File Explorer Pro as CIFS client on the tablet, and my Samba server is in version 4.2.10 on a Debian Jessie.

What's wrong with my configuration for Android clients ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After several tests, I discovered that option

```
server signing = mandatory
```

doesn't seem to be supported by Android clients.